# Application Insights for China region

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, asp.net-core, azure-application-insights

I'm working with Application Insights and in my region (Europe) I add it like this:

```csharp
services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(instrumentationKey);
```

Now I need to work with Application Insights in the China region. According to dock [learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/custom-endpoints?tabs=netcore) I updated the endpoints but it never started working for me. I still can't find the reason.

```csharp
services.ConfigureTelemetryModule<QuickPulseTelemetryModule>((module, o) => module.QuickPulseServiceEndpoint="https://quickpulse.applicationinsights.azure.cn/QuickPulseService.svc");
services.AddSingleton(new ApplicationInsightsApplicationIdProvider() { ProfileQueryEndpoint = "https://dc.applicationinsights.azure.cn/api/profiles/{0}/appId" }); 
services.AddSingleton<ITelemetryChannel>(new ServerTelemetryChannel() { EndpointAddress = "https://dc.applicationinsights.azure.cn/v2/track" });
services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry("china instrumentation key");
```

Then I tried to connect using ConnectionString, without modifying the endpoints and it worked, however I can't find any information about connecting to the China region using ConnectionString. I am worried that with such a connection some telemetry or other functions may not work, but I do not know how to check it.

So probably the key question for me is whether the ConnectionString itself is enough to connect and work with the China region.

UPD

- [Deprecating Instrumentation Key based SDK configuration in favor of Connection String.](https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/issues/2560)

> Warning
>
> Endpoint modification is not recommended. [Transition to connection strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/migrate-from-instrumentation-keys-to-connection-strings#migrate-from-application-insights-instrumentation-keys-to-connection-strings) to simplify configuration and eliminate the need for endpoint modification.
>
> ([Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/custom-endpoints?tabs=netcore))

Comment: Where did you deploy this web app when connecting to Azure China Application Insights? Europe or China?

Comment: It's not deployed anywhere right now, I'm testing it locally

Comment: Then you'd better deploy it and see if it starts to work. Keep in mind a connection from Europe (or North America) to China is rarely reliable and things can easily break. I think only tests within Azure China are valid.

Answer (score 2):

The recommended way is to use ConnectionString rather than overriding these endpoints. ConnectionString was created specifically to simplify non-Public cloud configurations.

The referred article was created before ConnectionString. Thank you for bringing it up, we will make it clear in the article that the recommended way is to use ConnectionString.